# YARN not able to add vcores

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a simple job on hadoop in pseudo distribute mode.

I only have a single machine and I would like to run using yarn a simple word count.

I run the application and it doesn't run, if I check the ResourceManager I think that I understand the problem, I don't have any vcore allocated.

[image]

When I check the status of the application I am running the status is

`ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.`

[image]

I believe that the problem is just to allocate a single vcore and some RAM, but I have no idea how to achieve this...

`user@user:~/hadoop-2.6.1$ jps
18420 Jps
11076 NameNode
8772 DataNode
15786 NodeManager
11296 SecondaryNameNode
16652 ResourceManager
simo@simo:~/hadoop-2.6.1$ jps
11076 NameNode
8772 DataNode
15786 NodeManager
11296 SecondaryNameNode
18881 Jps
16652 ResourceManager`

Comment: It looks like your NodeManager marked unhealthy by the ResourceManager; what do you see if you click through to "Unhealthy Nodes" on the first page and browse around for logs related to the unhealthy status?

Comment: Did you check the logs of your NodeManager? It seems NodeManager is either crashing or unable to connect to the ResourceManager. Hence, it is marked as Unhealthy.

Comment: The log are empty, the file does not exist... :(

Comment: I believe the problem is lack of physical memory... It can be possible ?

Comment: Without logs, I can't comment on what is the problem with NodeManager. But, I am sure that, there is some problem with NodeManager. That's why it is shown as Unhealthy

Comment: Yes, the problem was not enough physical space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was lack of physical space on my HD